# Show $U(2^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-2}}$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Let $U(2^n)$ denote the group of units modulo $2^n$. I really don't know how to attack this problem. My first thought is to attempt and construct an isomorphism. I want to send $x \in U(2^n)$ to $(1,m) \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-2}}$ if $x \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and to $(0,m)$ if $x \equiv 1 \mod 4$. I'm not yet sure how to determine $m$ though. This is primarily what i'm looking for. If what I have suggested so far is wrong please tell me. Any hints would be amazing, but a full solution is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Prove that $\langle3\rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup of $U(2^n)$, of order $2^{n-2}$.  Then just prove the group isn't cyclic.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!